# How to convert doc to docx using open xml sdk in c#

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, c++-cli

Please help me to convert .doc file to .docx using open xml sdk or any other method except word automation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

The OpenXML SDK allows you to manipulate only `.docx` files, not `.doc`. Here's a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/09/19/bulk-convert-doc-to-docx.aspx) illustrating how to perform bulk conversions of .doc to .docx files using a bulk conversion utility. I am afraid that if you don't want to use Word Automation, you will have to write your own `.doc` parser which might be quite a work.

Comment: For all intents and purposes, a half decent .doc parser is practically impossible. Just look at OpenOffice, it still chokes on a lot of doc files

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it, but take a look at http://b2xtranslator.sourceforge.net/.

In addition, if your scenario supports it, and if your business needs allow for it, it sometimes is effective to install a copy of SharePoint Server 2010, and use Word Automation Services.  Some people install a copy of SharePoint Server 2010 just to run Word Automation Services.  Word Automation Services has the capability of doing unattended server-side conversion of DOC to DOCX.

Depending on your scenario, Word Automation can be very troublesome.  In addition, if you are using Word Automation to serve specific functionality to a set of customers, then there may be licensing considerations.  Note that Word Automation is a different technology from Word Automation Services.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2010/12/07/what-is-the-difference-between-word-automation-and-word-automation-services.aspx for more info.