# How to read .doc and .docx file in .net without interop, openxml or Aspose?

Tags: c#, .net, openxml

I'm trying to read word document.
I am able to read .docx file with openXml, but getting error

> file contains corrupted datafor .doc file.

I don't want any paid library like [aspose](https://www.aspose.com/) and also it should work if word is not installed.

Comment: You can write your own parser then.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but can you please provide any example for it? it would be helpful for me

Comment: Writing your own parser for old `.doc` files is a rather huge task since the format is quite complex AFAIK. Therefor any kind of example for that would just be too much for an answer here on Stack Overflow. So I guess unless you find some kind of free library that is able to edit old `.doc` files (I don't know any) you will most likely need to look into some of the commercially available libraries such as Aspose, or use Interop to read these files (or just ditch the support for `.doc` files and stick to OpenXML and `.docx` files).

Comment: you can use https://npoi.codeplex.com/ can read doc,xlsx etc

Comment: openxml does not support .doc... You could try converting the .doc to a .docx and then read it... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489592/how-to-convert-doc-to-docx-using-open-xml-sdk-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 is writing your own library to solve the issue. Suggest not to take this option as this will become larger project than the one you are working on.

Option 2

> i don't want any paid library like aspose and also it should work if word is not installed.

You can use [Syncfusion docio](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/docio). There is a free license [here](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you are eligible. We are using it for our doc related parsing. We are happy with the library.